# Ajax IE ActiveXObject xhr.open("POST", url, true); -> Permission denied

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i m having a problem to make a ajax call to an api server with ie8
on my localhost it works: i can access to my localhost api server and to the api web server
but when i try to access my api web server from a site online (which is on the same server) i ve got an error: Permission Denied.
here's my code:

```
var xhr = null;  

if(jQuery.browser.msie == true && jQuery.browser.version < 9) { //IE < 9
    try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
} else { //other
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
        callback(reponse); //fonction à lancer après la requête ajax
    } else if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
        fail_handler(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", url, true); //ie8 says the error is here
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"); 
xhr.send(data);
```

an idea ?

Comment: Can you provide the full error? F12 for more info.

Comment: Is it a cross-origin request? (meaning, different domain, port, **or** protocol?)

Comment: Yes it is a Cross Domain request.
The full error message is: Permission Denied.
It works on all navigator except IE9 and lower.

Comment: jQuery doesn't support CORS in IE9 and older. Are you sure you're using the right XHR for IE to make a cross-origin request? (Hint: you're not. research XDomainRequest)

Comment: yes i m using xhr to make cross-origin request. it works on ie11. else i only tryed it on ie8 . i ll used xdr as you said. tku